# How to limit fps without set forceSetTimeOut=True in Phaser3

Tags: game-engine, phaser-framework

If i wanna limit fps to 30. i can only set forceSetTimeOut=True。But it’s not good as using requestAnimationFrame and count elapsed.

Is there anyway in phaser 3 to perform like the code below?

```
let fps = 30
let fpsInterval = 1000 / fps
let fpsLast

let transport = undefined

function setFps() {
    fpsLast = new Date().getTime()
}

function setScreen() {
    canvas.width = ctxWidth;
    canvas.height = ctxHeight;
}

function render() {
    frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(render)
    let now = new Date().getTime()
    let elapsed = now - fpsLast;
    if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
        fpsLast = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);
        if(gameRunning){
            main()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer answer your questions, or do you somemore information?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is, you could use the parameters `time` from the `update` function([link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.52.0/focus/Phaser.Scene-update)). **Beware:** The `update` function will be called about 60 times per second, but your code *inside the `if` clause* won't.

*As in the example, that you posted*

```
update (time, delta){
    // 1000ms divided by 31, just to be on the save side
    const timeNeededForAbout30Frame = 1000/31;
    if ((time - this.lastRun) > timeNeededForAbout30Frame ){
        this.lastRun = time;
        // ... here comes the code 
    }
}
```

> **Info:** I would rather use the `fpsConfig` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Core.html#.FPSConfig)), but since with this config the target fps, are not enforced, just a *"hint"* it might not work for you.